# Role management issue in Flask-Dance

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, flask-dance

I am using Flask-Dance to integrate Google login/signup into my app having two different roles i.e. patient and staff. I had created different login/signup routes for them. The issue I am facing right now is passing `role` to my callback route so I can set it in DB. In my signup route, I am creating the URL like this:

```
google_signup_link = url_for('google.login', next=url_for('main.google_login', _external=True), role=PATIENT)
```

I am configuring my Google blueprint like this:

```
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
        client_id=secrets['google']['client_id'],
        client_secret=secrets['google']['client_secret'],
        scope=['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
        redirect_to='main.google_login'
    )
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint, url_prefix='/google_login')
```

But, when I try to access the role parameter in my callback function it is not found hence I end up setting the role to `None`. Here is my callback route:

```
@main.route('/google-login')
def google_login():
    role = request.args.get('role')
```

I would appreciate the help in passing the role in the callback route without storing it in session or anywhere.
Thanks!